# View previous due date after change in Trello

Tags: trello

My client keeps changing their due dates. Which is fine but I want to know what the original due date was to see how far behind we are.

Is this possible? It doesn’t seem to appear in the activity except “Amanda W
Due date amended—designer pushed back her delivery date.”

Answer (score 2):

The best way to keep track of history like this is to add a line to the card description.

Original Due Date:

Trello boards are always showing the current state of all cards/lists.

Comment: thanks Kevan. That's not very foolproof and thought it might be built in somehow.

Comment: No, it's not foolproof and it does not display on Calendar either.  However, doing it this way is as close as you can currently get to what you described.