# How can I stop anyone from changing a due date on Trello

Tags: trello

I would like to know how to stop other team members from changing a due date after I open a card on a board.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lock down individual cards on a Trello board: if a team member has editing permissions on your board, they can also edit due dates of cards.

What you *can* do is restrict a team member's rights to the board in general: if you make them an "Observer" they will by default only have read-access to the board, preventing them from changing due dates. You can then permit Observers to also add comments. [This answer has more detail.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91934/95210)

A related question that may be helpful is [View previous due date after change in Trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59606/view-previous-due-date-after-change-in-trello?rq=1).